# Keep OrientDB server running on AWS EC2

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2, orientdb

I recently downloaded and managed to start an OrientDB server/database on an AWS EC2 Linux 14.04 (I think the name is) server for an application I want to set up. I started OrientDB "as usual" by running ./server.sh in the terminal via SSH link to the EC2 server. All works fine and I can query the database while at the computer. But as soon as I leave my computer and the SSH link is broken (for example when closing the computer), so is the database, i.e. it stops.

Is there a way to go around this or do I have to set up the database in some other way?

Comment: How do you launch it?

Comment: By running the server.sh (./server.sh) file from the terminal in the bin folder of OrientDB. This starts the OrientDB server. @OleksandrGubchenko

Comment: Which EC2 instance type did you use? I am trying the micro (free) but getting an insufficient memory error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OrientDB is provided as AWS AMI. Take a look to

http://orientdb.com/orientdb-amazon-web-services/

If you want to DIY, follow the instructions provided on

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Unix-Service.html

Update: new link to doc:

https://orientdb.com/docs/last/admin/Unix-Service.html

Hope this helps

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you. Missed that page on Orient's website. Working like a charm. @Roberto

Comment: @Roverto Franchini Out of curiosity (since it would be easier to set up the db from the studio compared to the console, UI wise), how do I connect to the AWS AMI version?

Comment: Usually, it is exposed on port 2480, e.g. localhost:2480. So, I guess it is exposed on port 2480 of the running instance if it is open.

Comment: The second link is broken as is the link on their website for installation methods.

Comment: Now the second link is broken.. it worked just the other day! This is getting annoying. Seems to be this now.. https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Unix-Service.html

Answer (score 2):

you can try putting full path to server.sh into /etc/rc.local before exit 0 and reboot the instance

Comment: Thank you! Haven't tried this but I think this would work. Similar to this one: https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/34708676-starting-something-on-boot @Ruslan

Answer (score 0):

Before running the server, run the command:

screen

This will create a persistent environment which will allow your process to keep running after you disconnect.

When you reconnect, you can use this command to reconnect to that environment:

screen -r